# NodeJS running with SSL, Apache2 Proxy not working

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have been trying to run a NodeJS application that can be accessed with :x (port number) fine but it is running on a subdomain that is

```
subdomain.domain.com:x
```

When the NodeJS application is served with `http` server having no SSL Configuration, Apache configurations work fine and `new.domain.com` is proxied to `subdomain.domain.com:x` just fine.

But when the NodeJS application is server with `https`, Apache generates 502 Bad Gateway errors. Below is the configuration I've been using. I tried everything but it just won't work.

Please note that I have replaced the original port numbers and subdomains to random names in order to hide the real domain names.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        ServerName new.domain.com 

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile <Path/To/SSLCertificate>/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile <Path/To/SSLCertificateKeyFile>/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://subdomain.domain.com:x/
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.domain.com-access.log combined
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.domain.com-error.log

   ServerName new.domain.com   
   Redirect "/" "https://new.domain.com/"

</VirtualHost>
```

The NodeJS is running in a pretty simple settings too which are as follows;

```
const https = require("https"),
  fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/srv/www/keys/my-site-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/srv/www/keys/chain.pem")
};

const app = express();

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
});

app.listen(8000);

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080);
```